# Nice screencast tutorials for programming

Tags: language-agnostic

i am looking for a website that provides nice screencasts and tutorials about programming and webdesign.

Currently i am using http://net.tutsplus.com. I think this one is pretty nice. Anyone know of any good alternatives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry but i think the websites in the answers are pretty basic tutorials. I think tutsplus is pretty different esp for graphic designs.

I found two links that are list for top tutorial websites on the net. The websites in the list are pretty awesome with canned example and esp nice inspiration for advanced projects.

Top 20 earning web design websites:
http://www.webdesigndev.com/roundups/top-20-earning-web-design-websites

Top 5 Web Resource Sites:
http://www.cindisimonson.com/blog/top-10-web-related-resources/

I hope you guys like it, they definitely help me get inspiration for my projects.

Answer (score 5):

I've found the screen casts from [Tekpub](http://www.tekpub.com) very useful... which has now been bought out by [Pluralsight](https://www.pluralsight.com/)

Since your already on Stack Overflow you'll probably enjoy blogs by the site creators.

https://blog.codinghorror.com/

http://www.joelonsoftware.com

Answer (score 1):

Not completely language agnostic, but of very good quality for all things that are .NET: http://www.dnrtv.com/

Answer (score 0):

You might like [the w3 schools](http://www.w3schools.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Depends what it is you're trying to learn there some good ASP.NET MVC ones on the [Microsoft site](http://www.asp.net/learn/mvc-videos/).

Answer (score 0):

For ruby on rails: http://railscasts.com/

For git: http://gitcasts.com/

Answer (score 0):

http://www.roseindia.net/

- Core Java
- JSP
- Servlet
- JDBC
- Hibernate
- Struts 1
- Struts 2
- JSF
- Spring
- J2EE
- J2ME
- Web Services
- Ajax
- Dojo
- MySQL
- Flex
- Ant